# JQVmap with custom region

Tags: javascript, web, jqvmap

I need to create a map of a region that doesn't exist in the standard jqvMap, so I need to create that new region and I can't find any article on the internet on how to do this.
The region I need is "[Baixada Santista](https://www.agem.sp.gov.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/reg680.pdf)", there are a total of 9 cities on the coast of São Paulo, in Brazil.

If it is not possible with jqvMap, could you please indicate a platform on which I could put this functionality